# Counting numbers per hour between a start and end time

Tags: sql-server, excel, date, datetime

I have an attendance management system where start and end times are recorded for each attendance. I can easily calculate the duration of stay by taking start time away from end time.

An example of the data would be like this: -

```
VisitUID          | AttendeeID   | Start_time              | End_time
0  -----          123  -----     01/01/2015 09:15  -----   01/01/2015 17:15
1  -----          456  -----     01/01/2015 10:45  -----   01/01/2015 16:30
2  -----          753  -----     01/01/2015 08:05  -----   01/01/2015 17:45
3  -----          975  -----     01/01/2015 07:15  -----   01/01/2015 15:05
4  -----          864  -----     01/01/2015 15:55  -----   01/01/2015 16:25
5  -----          246  -----     01/01/2015 16:00  -----   01/01/2015 17:35
6  -----          357  -----     01/01/2015 11:10  -----   01/01/2015 14:55
```

So a count would be something like this (please excuse me if I have counted wrong!): -

```
07 - 1
08 - 2
09 - 3
10 - 4
11 - 5
12 - 5
13 - 5
14 - 5
15 - 5
16 - 5
17 - 3
```

What I am trying to figure out is a way to count how many people were on site in each hour to understand the numbers on site?

The system is SQL and the start and end are datetime values so a way of calculating this in SQL or even Excel would be amazing.

Comment: Would you mind adding the query which you tried so far?

Comment: SUM() a CASE Expression that returns 1 if the person was there during the hour in question, or 0 if they were not.

Comment: What is the first column of the expected results?  If that is hour of day it doesn't match the sample data.  If you need to span days, you'll also need a date.

Comment: There can be hours only from 07 up to 17?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data are already in a SQL Server database, it is not necessary to get them out and into Excel. It can be done with just a couple line of SQL. If you prefer Excel, you have some good options as well above or below.

You first need a table with all the possible hours: `values(7), (8), ...`
It can then be joined with your data when the hour from this table is between start and end dates.

**Your Data:**

```
declare @date table(VisitUID int, AttendeeID int, Start_time datetime, End_time datetime)
Insert Into @date(VisitUID, AttendeeID, Start_time, End_time) values
    (0, 123, '01/01/2015 09:15', '01/01/2015 17:15')
    , (1, 456, '01/01/2015 10:45', '01/01/2015 16:30')
    , (2, 753, '01/01/2015 08:05', '01/01/2015 17:45')
    , (3, 975, '01/01/2015 07:15', '01/01/2015 15:05')
    , (4, 864, '01/01/2015 15:55', '01/01/2015 16:25')
    , (5, 246, '01/01/2015 16:00', '01/01/2015 17:35')
    , (6, 357, '01/01/2015 11:10', '01/01/2015 14:55')
```

**Query:**

```
Select h.n, COUNT(*)
From (values(7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18)) as h(n)
Inner Join @date d on 
    h.n >= DATEPART(hour, d.Start_time) 
    and  h.n <= DATEPART(hour, d.End_time)+1
Group by h.n
```

If you need data from 0 to 7 or 18 to 0, just add them to the list: `values(6), (7), (8)...(18)...`

It seems that your calculation is correct. I have the same output.

**Output:**

```
Hour    Count
7       1
8       2
9       3
10      4
11      5
12      5
13      5
14      5
15      5
16      5
17      3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Julien. There are some really good suggestions here

Answer (score 2):

Excel. For another downvote :)

[image]

The formula in F3 copied across and down to suit is:

```
=--AND(HOUR($C3)<G$2,HOUR($D3)>=F$2)
```

The formula in F1 and copied across is:

```
 =SUM(F3:F1000)
```

Comment: a very elegant solution!

Comment: nope ... I upvoted your answer as I really like the idea of extracting hours only to get (an average) daily profile.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNPIVOT` in following:

**QUERY**

```
;with cte as
(
select   DATEPART(hh,Start_time) StartTime
       , DATEPART(hh,End_time) EndTime
       , CASE WHEN 7 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,Start_time) AND DATEPART(hh,End_time) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [7]
       , CASE WHEN 8 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,Start_time) AND DATEPART(hh,End_time) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [8]
       , CASE WHEN 9 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,Start_time) AND DATEPART(hh,End_time) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS [9]
       , CASE WHEN 10 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,Start_time) AND DATEPART(hh,End_time) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [10]
       , CASE WHEN 11 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,Start_time) AND DATEPART(hh,End_time) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [11]
       , CASE WHEN 12 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,Start_time) AND DATEPART(hh,End_time) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [12]
       , CASE WHEN 13 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,Start_time) AND DATEPART(hh,End_time) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [13]
       , CASE WHEN 14 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,Start_time) AND DATEPART(hh,End_time) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [14]
       , CASE WHEN 15 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,Start_time) AND DATEPART(hh,End_time) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [15]
       , CASE WHEN 16 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,Start_time) AND DATEPART(hh,End_time) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [16]
       , CASE WHEN 17 BETWEEN DATEPART(hh,Start_time) AND DATEPART(hh,End_time) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [17]
from #test
)
select StartTime1 StartTime, sum(Cnt) Counter
from(
select StartTime,[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17]
from cte
) p
UNPIVOT
(
    Cnt FOR StartTime1 IN ([7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17])
)AS unpvt
group by StartTime1
order by CAST(StartTIme1 AS INT)
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
create table #test
(
VisitUID   INT,
AttendeeID INT,
Start_time DATETIME,
End_time   DATETIME,
)
insert into #test values
(0, 123,'01/01/2015 09:15','01/01/2015 17:15'),
(1, 456,'01/01/2015 10:45','01/01/2015 16:30'),
(2, 753,'01/01/2015 08:05','01/01/2015 17:45'),
(3, 975,'01/01/2015 07:15','01/01/2015 15:05'),
(4, 864,'01/01/2015 15:55','01/01/2015 16:25'),
(5, 246,'01/01/2015 16:00','01/01/2015 17:35'),
(6, 357,'01/01/2015 11:10','01/01/2015 14:55')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
StartTime   Counter
7           1
8           2
9           3
10          4
11          5
12          5
13          5
14          5
15          5
16          5
17          3
```

Comment: OK ... "Jedem Tierchen sein Pläsierchen" ... I for my part prefer enjoying puzzles and ansewring questions *ggg*

Comment: @JulienVavasseur what are you talking about? I first here got down-voted... After It I had up-votes. And what there you see complicated with unpivot?

Comment: @Stanislovas Kalašnikovas Although it is working, I just feel this contains a lot of computation and testing and then transformation in one single query while the requierement is not that complicated.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

in this picture the following cells contain following formulas / constants ...

F3 ... `01.01.2015  00:00:00`

G3 ... `=F3+TIME(1;0;0)`  ... copy this right until AC3

F4 ... `=IF(AND(F$3>=$D4;F$3<$E4);1;0)` ... copy this right/down until AC10

F12 ... `=SUM(F4:F11)` ... copy this right until AC12

The essence here is to check if the user login period 'encloses' a point in time you want to test for (e.g. test_time >= start_time AND test_time < end_time) ... whereby you can get philosophic wheter it's >= and < or > and <=

Now ... if you want a daily activity curve without hardcoding the date in the heading, you can have only the time in the header and compare it against the time part of the user login/out dates (as in =date-INT(date) ...)

Comment: You chart goes from 8 or 9 to 18. Should not it be from 7 to 17 because it start at 7:15 for uid 3? It seems it slip by 1 h.

Comment: the chart is a bonus rather ... but I thought if I'm doing stuff like this I'd like to have it presented grapically ... for the two 4's let me check

Comment: @JulienVavasseur strictly speaking you are right ... however I asume the OP will not disallow users from logging in earlier and work later ... so what I wanted to show is an **abstraction** that can be applied at any daytime

Comment: @MikeD nothing wrong with hours before 7 and until 24. But according to its output and data, it seems that it should be 1 between 7 and 8. On the chart it is 1  between 8 and 9. And so on...

Comment: @pnuts well spotted ... the poisener is VisitUID=4 ... visiting less than an hour ... so here the great formula hits its limits *ggg* ... thinking ...

Comment: @JulienVavasseur correct ... it's depending on where in the comparison you introduce the equal signe (front or back) ... this will shift the "classes" left/right by 1

Comment: @MikeD well 4 was there at 15:xx and at 16:xx although you are right, he didn't stay long. There is no mention of the duration of the visit in the question though.

Answer (score 1):

> ...or even Excel would be amazing.

Assuming your data are in columns A:D, select 11 contiguously vertical cells and paste the following into the Formula Bar and confirm with CONTROL-ENTER:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ROWS($1:1)+6>=HOUR(C$2:C$99))*(ROWS($1:1)+6<=HOUR(D$2:D$99)))
```

Note: if the attendance data extend beyond row 99 then increase the 99s in the formula appropriately.

Comment: Worked a charm, thanks Excel Hero. The is probably the easiest solution of all those suggested but I will vote one of the SQL based ones as the answer given that would save me first getting the data into excel.